# OBDII Car-Hacking

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, automotive, obd

Can I implement an OBD-II scanner using an ATMEGA328P in place of the ELM 327? Preferably read some diagnostics code and upload that data to a web app via mqtt using GSM module.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Keep in mind that *"Is it possible ...?"* is a yes/no question. In this case, the answer is "Yes". If you're asking us to design it for you, that would be too broad. You would need to specify something about the level of performance you expect as well as what constraints you have on the implementation. What is your specific question?

Comment: Performance-wise, I was looking to implement one just as good as that of the elm 327 but compact and discrete. However, I have a limited budget of $ 60. I'd be testing the implementation on a Pontiac Vibe or Honda Accord Sport (2016) depending on the car's availability.

Answer (score 0):

The ELM327 is a product, not a component. The original device bearing this name was implemented with a PIC18 microcontroller.

I don't see any inherent reason why a similar device couldn't be implemented with an AVR microcontroller. That being said, you might be better off using a microcontroller with a CAN peripheral, as that's what OBD uses for communications.

Comment: Minor correction, OBD doesn't *need* to use CAN for comms. There's other protocols as well (e.g. K-Line).

Comment: @Shamtam Fair point. My understanding is that CAN is nearly universal in any car made in the last ~10 years, though.

Comment: There are still multiple OBDII protocol variants (including RS232) and CAN based is only one of them: http://obdtester.com/obd2_protocols    The ELM327 is sold as a chip (https://www.elmelectronics.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/ELM327DS.pdf) and although clearly implemented in an MCU that is beside the point. ….it is sold as a component.

Answer (score 0):

There are several open source code bases for using Arduino (ATMega327 based) as an OBDII diagnostic tool. The majority are RS232/ISO-K based implementations and all OBDII ports have at least some level of support for the serial connection.
More advanced and manufacturer specific commands may only be available over the CAN (or other) interfaces used in the most modern vehicles.

Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBDuino) and [here](http://rvmiller.com/present/CS497_presentation_miller.pdf) for OBDuino information as a starting point.
Source code readily available on [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/obdcon/).